# cannot extract item element from xml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am trying to extract all of the `item` elements from the xml file at https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=goog&region=US&lang=en-US so that I can then access the `title` and `link` for each element which I can then perform some other functions on.

The xml has the following structure:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
    <title> </title>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
    <language></language>
    <lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate>
    <image>
    <url></url>
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <width></width>
    <height></height>
    </image>
    <item>
        <title></title>
        <link></link>
        <description></description>
        <guid></guid>
        <pubDate></pubDate>
    </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I have written the following code:

```
import urllib
from xml.etree import ElementTree


class News():

    base_url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s='
    query = 'goog'

    url = base_url + query
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()

    dom = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
    items = dom.findall('channel/item/')


    for item in items:
        print item.text
```

Which outputs every element inside the `<channel>` element e.g.

```
Google funds 128 news projects in Europe
http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/*http://sg.finance.yahoo.com/news/google-funds-128-news-projects-211927426.html
None
yahoo_finance/2067775856
Wed, 24 Feb 2016 21:19:27 GMT
```

However, I cannot work out how to access the elements inside the `<item>` element.
I have tried the following code:

```
for item in items:

        title = item.find('title')
        print title.text
```

But I get the following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

How can I access the `title` and `link` elements inside the `item` element? Thanks

Comment: Can you correct your  XML indentation for better understandig of it's structure?

Comment: done! think that is right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the slash at dom.findAll('channel/item') did the trick. Sample code just outputs the title

```
import urllib
from xml.etree import ElementTree


class News():

    base_url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s='
    query = 'goog'

    url = base_url + query
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()

    dom = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
    items = dom.findall('channel/item')


    for item in items:
        print(item.find('title').text)
```

Output is just the title:

```
Google launches 'Accelerated Mobile Pages' feature in India
The Death of Oscar Trivia
Meet Atlas, Boston Dynamics' New Humanoid Robot
[$$] Business Watch
Google Fiber Heads To San Francisco; Faster Search Service Coming
U.S. Justice Dept., Silicon Valley discuss online extremism
Google Fiber to Expand to Tech Hub
Behind Google's Deepmind Healthcare App
Google Renews Push for ‘Fair Use’ of APIs Before Oracle Trial
Forget Keyboards: We Dictated This Story on Google Docs
U.S. aviation regulator starts rule-making process for public drone flights
Android N could stand for No App Drawer: Why that's an epic mistake
Google is putting its video streaming gadget directly inside TVs
These Google Maps glitches are the stuff of nightmares
Google launches AMP for faster web page loading
Microsoft to buy app-development startup Xamarin
Will Users Like Facebook’s New Selection of ‘Reactions?’ — Tech Roundup
France Says Google Owes 1.6 Billion Euros in Back Taxes
Google speeds news to smartphones, challenging Facebook
Google funds 128 news projects in Europe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
root = lxml.fromstring(data)
results = root.findall('channel/item/')
texts = [r.find('title').text for r in results]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach using lxml/XPath:

```
import requests
import lxml.etree

r = requests.get('https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=goog&region=US&lang=en-US')
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)

items = tree.xpath('//item')

def fst(i):
    if i: return i[0]
    else: return ''

data = []
for i in items:
    entry = {
        'title'   : fst(i.xpath('title/text()')),
        'link'    : fst(i.xpath('link/text()')),
        'guid'    : fst(i.xpath('guid/text()')),
        'pubDate' : fst(i.xpath('pubDate/text()')),
        'description' : fst(i.xpath('description/text()')),
    }
    data.append(entry)

for entry in data:
    print entry['title']
```